# In HTML/CSS, how can images be treated such that they do not go offscreen, requiring scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm writing some code for a simple slideshow that is intended to display a single, full image at a time and to advance to other images using arrow keys. I want every image to be displayed in full on the screen such that the user is not required to scroll in order to see the full image; the image is sized such that its maximum height is the browser height if the image is more high than wide and such that its maximum width is the browser width if the image is more wide than high.

How can this be done? Currently my code requires the user to scroll to see the bottom of images that are more high than wide. I have set the `img` CSS style to `max-height: 100%` and `max-width: 100%`.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>slideshow</title>
<style type="text/css">
    html, body{
        background: #333333;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: Arial Black;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 1.5;
        text-align: justify;
    }
    img{
        padding: 0;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-height: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        object-fit: contain;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div id="slideshow">
        <img
            alt="slideshow"
            src="http://i.imgur.com/hPvyf52.png"
            id="image_slide"
            onclick="change_image()"
        />
    </div>
</div>
<script>
var images = [
    "1.png",
    "2.png",
    "3.png",
    "4.png",
    "5.png"
];
var index = 0;
var images_length = images.length-1;

function change_image(direction){
    var img = document.getElementById("image_slide");
    var img_preload_next_1 = new Image()
    var img_preload_next_2 = new Image()

    if(direction == "next"){
        index++;
    }else{
        index--;
    }

    if(index > images_length){
        index = 0;
    }else if(index < 0){
        index = images_length;
    }

    img.src = images[index];
    img_preload_next_1.src = images[index + 1];
    img_preload_next_2.src = images[index + 2];
}

document.onkeydown = function(event){
    event = event || window.event;

    if (event.keyCode == "37"){
        change_image("previous"); 
    }else if (event.keyCode == "39"){
        change_image("next");
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try object-fit: contain

Comment: Note, that `event.keyCode` is deprecated, which actually is originally an IE feature only. All modern browsers support [`e.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an `img` tag, set the background of the div as follows.

```
background-size: contain;
background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/hPvyf52.png);
height: 100%;
width: 100%
```

Then swap the background image.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Would this preserve the aspect ratio of the images?

Comment: Yes that is what background-size: contain is for.

Comment: Thanks again for that. It worked well. I've added a minimal working example  implementing your suggestion to your answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should set the width and height of the container. Styling `img` to 100% will get the exact size of the image. 
They setting the container dimensions. You can also try `overflow:hidden`

Comment: The problem is not overflow.